# Unidirectional RS not posible with JHipster tech studio

Tags: jhipster

I would like to create a unidirectional many-to-one rs. I use the jdl studio to generate everything: https://start.jhipster.tech/jdl-studio/

```
relationship ManyToOne{
    A to B
}

entity A{
   name String
}

entity B{
   name String
}
```

According to the documentation it should work:
https://www.jhipster.tech/jdl/#jdlrelationships

But the output is always a bidirectional rs:

**B.java**

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "b")
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
private Set<A> as = new HashSet<>();
```

**A.java**

```
@ManyToOne
@JsonIgnoreProperties("as")
private B b;
```

What am I doing wrong?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

The below JDL relationship section will result in a unidirectional relationship, [as documented.](https://www.jhipster.tech/managing-relationships/#2) This will only have the relationship on the `A` side.

```
relationship ManyToOne{
    A{b} to B
}
```

If you want `B` to have a list of `A` entities, use:

```
relationship ManyToOne{
    A to B
}
```

Comment: thank you but I would like the One site to be the owner of the relationship so it would look like this:                                                                                   
                                                                                                                  relationship ManyToOne{
    A to B{a}
} but this doesnt work!

Comment: I don't think what you are trying to achieve is not possible.  The foreign key is stored on the `Many` side, not the `One` side.  On a related point, unidirectional relationships are less efficient than bidirectional relationships, and should be avoided unless required. See point 7 in https://vladmihalcea.com/14-high-performance-java-persistence-tips/

Comment: what I am trying to achieve is that B class has a list of A's and with @JoinColumn the reference is in the A class.

Comment: JHipster does not generate a `@JoinColumn` annotation in OneToMany relationships.  If you want to use that annotation, you will have to edit the relationships manually.